# Prove $\sup(A)\leq\inf(B)$

Tags: real-analysis

$A$ and $B$ are two non-empty subsets of the real set.
Given that 
$$(x \in A \text{ and } y \in B) \implies x\leq y$$ 
Show that $\sup A$ and $\inf B$ exists and that $\sup A\leq\inf B$

Comment: What's hard? What have you tried. This is really straightforward.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: I have no other given than the above. Can I say that as $x\leq y$ then $sup(x) \leq y$ for every $y \in B$ therefore $sup(x) \leq inf(y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re your comment: that's almost right. But you have to pick some $y\in B$, which gives an actual upper bound for all $x\in A$.

Notice the assumption that $A,B$ are nonempty: you're not using it. If $B$ is empty then it's true that "for all $y\in B, whatever$". If $B$ is empty, then you have NOT shown that $A$ has an upper bound! (try $A=\Bbb R, B=\emptyset$), so you can't conclude that $\sup A$ exists. It also doesn't exist if $A = \emptyset$, so the nonemptiness of $A$ is essential too.

Once you establish that it does exist, though, the same reasoning shows that $\sup A\le y$ for any $y\in B$. Thus $\sup A$ is a lower bound for $B$, and you can conclude that it is $\le \inf B$.